# Remove euro sign and space in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this in XML:

```
<price>
  <now>€ 249,95</now>
</price>
```

The amount before the comma is done below, I only want to remove the euro sign as well.

This is what is have (XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:template name="amount">
  <xsl:param name="string"/>
  <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($string,$separator)">

        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string,$separator)"/>  

    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: `substring-after($string," ")`?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do simply:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(now, ',€ ', '.')" />
```

This will convert the decimal comma to a dot and remove the Euro symbol along with any spaces - without needing to test if any of them exist.

If you want only the integer part, then:

```
<xsl:value-of select="floor(translate(now, ',€ ', '.'))" />
```

will return `249` in your example.